# Certificar Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth2, google-oauth

hice una aplicacion web con GAS, y queda muy feo que al iniciar sesion diga que no fue verificado por google, y que el usuario tenga que ir a configuracion avanzada, etc. Se ve re turbio.

Cómo hay que hacer para verificar eso y que no salga? hay que incluir algun certificado SSL?

Agradezco cualquiera que me pueda dar una mano!

Answer (score 1):

Véase esta otra respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/538539/65

---

El término que usa Google es "verificar". Lo primero que deberás hacer es

1. Crear un proyecto de Google Cloud
2. Configurar el consentimiento de OAuth
3. Agregar el número de proyecto del proyecto de Google Cloud al proyecto de Google Apps Script.

Luego podrás solicitar la verificación de tu app.

Recursos

- [OAuth Client Verification | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)
- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
- [Setting up your OAuth consent screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en)
- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

La leyenda en inglés es "This application was created by another user, not by Google", en español sería "Esta aplicación fue creada por otro usuario, no por Google".

De acuerdo a [un comentario](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63521070#comment4) de un empleado de Google (encontrado gracias a [comentario de Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635284/google-apps-script-remove-warning-banner#comment112609242_33635284)), esta leyenda se mostrará si aplicación fue creada con una cuenta de gmail.com y es accedida por otro usuario o bien si fue creada con una cuenta de ahora llamado Google Workspace y es accedida por un usuario de otro dominio.

Crear un proyecto de Google Cloud Platform y verificar la aplicación no resolverá esto, la única forma es embeber la aplicación en otra página web, por ejemplo en Google Sites, Google Firebase, Wordpress, etc. Para esto en el código de Google Apps Script deberá agregarse `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)` al objeto [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output), por ejemplo:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); 
}
```

En el caso de Google Sites, usar el widget para insertar código, y poner el URL de la aplicación web (URL con `/exec`).

En el caso de páginas web que permitan el uso de la etiqueta iframe, usar esta, por ejemplo:

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/.../exec"></iframe>
```

Relacionado

- [Google Apps Script remove warning banner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635284/1595451)